# jquery get IIS web application name?

Tags: jquery

I've a mvc .net app deployed in IIS with web app = 'appTest'. Is it possible to get the web app name in jQuery?

Thanks in advance, 
Ben

Comment: Umm....What?.........^^

Comment: something like this: var appName = location.AppName;

Comment: I was hoping there is something like this: var appName = location.AppName;    so that I can format var url = '/' + appName + '/Test/Page1?Param=1'